# What are good use cases for JavaScript self executing anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, theory

I understand what a self executing anonymous function is but I am having trouble understanding where I would use them and why.  This could be because I often use jQuery.  Could you please provide examples of good use cases?

Comment: Anonymous function that uses the loop index as a free variable in a loop

Comment: For an example, see the answer by neurosnap in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, a self-executing anonymous function (more technically referred to as an IIFE or immediately invoked function expression) is the same as declaring a named function and then immediately calling it.  The only difference with an IIFE is that is has no name so it can only be executed in place (not called from elsewhere) and consequently doesn't add a name to the current namespace.

So, you can use one any time that having a bunch of code inside a function would be useful and when that code only ever needs to be called in the currently defined context.

Some places where this is common:

1. In any kind of loop that involves some local variables and some asynchronous operations (ajax, timeout, etc...) where you want access to those local variables separately for each loop iteration in the asynchronous completion function.
2. To encapsulate some top level code that runs once with it's own scope and own local variables that are private and separate from the global namespace.
3. To create a unnamed function scope for any reason.

Examples:

Loop Index (freezes the loop index separately for each invocation of `setTimeout()`):

```
for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    // capture the loop index into in a closure
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(index);
        }, 2000);
    })(i);
}
```

Top Level Code Encapsulation (creates private, but persistent variable that is not in the global scope):

```
(function() {
    var cntr = 0;
    window.getUniqueId = function() {
        return ++cntr;
    };
})();
```

Create locally available shortcut variables in code that would otherwise be top level scope.

```
function Dictionary(initialData) {
    // call parent constructor
    Set.apply(this, arguments);
}

(function() {
    // inherit from Set
    var proto = Dictionary.prototype = new Set();
    var base = Set.prototype;
    // Set constructor back to us
    proto.constructor = Dictionary;

    // override of the base class .add()
    // add(key, value)
    // add(Dictionary)
    // add({key1: value1, key2: value2})
    proto.add = function(arg1, arg2) {
        if (arg1 instanceof Set) {
            // call base class to just add another Set
            base.add.call(this, arg1);
        } else if (typeof arg1 === "object") {
            // cycle through the object and add all properties/values to the Set
            for (var prop in arg1) {
                if (arg1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    this._add(prop, arg1[prop]);
                }
            }
        } else if (typeof arg2 !== "undefined") {
            // must be add(key, value)
            this._add(arg1, arg2);
        }
        return this;
    }

    proto.get = function(key) {
        return this.data[key];
    }

    // See rest of code here: https://github.com/jfriend00/Javascript-Set/blob/master/dictionary.js

})();
```

Comment: Actually asynchronous operations here would just confuse OP. You could have the same case with synchronous callback passed to `map` or `filter` as well

Comment: @zerkms - there's no need to capture the loop index if the operations are all synchronous as the loop index will be valid in the synchronous callback.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

It is used in several common ways:

1. It is self contained and any declared variable in the IIFE won't contaminated the global space.  Example:

   `(function() {
       var foo = 123; 
       $(".pop-up-trigger").click(function() {
           // ...
       });
   }());`
2. To create "private variables" in JavaScript.  By declaring some local variables, and then returning some functions, these functions can access those local variables (assign them or get the values).  Outside of the IIFE, no code can touch those local variables and therefore they are private.
3. To create a scope.  JavaScript has no block scope but only has function scope, so by having a function and invoking it, there is a new scope created.