# Javascript: variable redeclaration in functions causing undefined

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

Why does `console.log(foo)` produce `undefined` instead of `'bar'` in —

```
var foo = 'bar';
(function() {
    console.log(foo);
    if(foo === 'baz') {
        var foo = 'qux';
    }
})();
```

— but produces `'bar'` if `var foo` is replaced with `foo`? I know that it's bad practice to redeclare variables, but `var foo = 'qux'` is never evaluated anyways, and even if it were, it still shouldn't do anything, right?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfL9kxxj/)

Comment: Other duplicates: [Javascript variable scope return undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291183/javascript-variable-scope-return-undefined/26291206#26291206) and a [good article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript "hoists" variable declarations, meaning that variable declarations that occur later in code are "hoisted" to the top of their containing scope. This means that:

```
(function() {
    console.log(foo);
    if(foo === 'baz') {
        var foo = 'qux'
    }
});
```

becomes:

```
(function() {
    var foo;
    console.log(foo);
    if(foo === 'baz') {
         foo = 'qux'
    }
});
```

even though the reassignment/"redeclaration" of `foo` is never explicitly run. [Adequately Good](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) sums up hoisting far more than adequately.

However, at first glance, our example looks like a case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888506/redeclaring-a-javascript-variable). The trick is that, because functions have their own scope *inherited* from their containing scopes (in this case, the global one), declaring any variable, even if it exists in the inherited scope, is guaranteed to be `undefined` before assignment.

---

I initially wanted to pose this question because I thought it was the fault of `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` that code like this constantly threw `Cannot set property 'className' of undefined`:

```
var timer;
document.getElementById('ele').addEventListener('mousewheel', function() {
    var that = this;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        that.className = 'foo';
        if(false) { //this condition shouldn't have ever been true in my test cases
            var that = document.getElementById('otherEle');
            setTimeout(function() { /* Things to do with otherEle in 1s */ }, 1000);
        }
    }, 200);
}, false);
```

I later found out that the `var that` redeclaration was the culprit and, after some research, concluded that hoisting and function scoping were to blame. Still, I don't know if my explanation of scoping was entirely accurate, and would appreciate feedback.

Comment: Your explanation is spot on.  Some programmers declare all variables at the top of their scope to help avoid problems like this (or in your case, `that`).